# Given list of integers,remove odd positions of the list(starting from position 1(index 0) until the list contains a single element in minimum time

Tags: python, list, time-complexity

I'm given a list of numbers,I need to remove the odd positions of the list  until my list contains a single number
Given list: (0,1,1,2,3,5,8,3,1)
Explanation:(1,2,5,3)
            (2,3)
            (3)
Answer:3
Constraint:1 ≤ No. of elements of the list ≤ 10^18

I've tried to find the solution using slicing in loop but as the no. of elements can vary from 1 to 10^18 it will take a lot of time to complete the operation.Therefore I'm searching for an optimized solution.

```py
while(len(R)>1):
    R=R[1::2]
print(R[0])
```

The output was as expected but takes a lot of time to execute when the no. of elements is increased.So searching for an optimized solution.

Comment: If you have a numerical array this big, you should consider using an optimised array library like numpy. It will be much faster.

Comment: What about splitting lists to even sized sublists and then removing odd elements parallel - then joining the final list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it without looping.

```py
l = [0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 3, 1,2,3]
import math
i=2**math.floor(math.log(len(l),2))
ans=l[i-1]
print(ans)
```

Comment: This is actually correct - I amended my answer after it was accepted incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

This answer was accepted before it was correct, credit goes to @rahul verma for pointing out the answer was a bit more complex. The answer previously gave a solution that only works in specific cases.

If the required answer is only the final element in the last list with a single element, then computing what the index of the element would be in the original list is far more efficient than actually processing the lists.

In this case, the result is the element at the index equal to the largest power of two that's equal to or smaller than the length of the list, minus one (since a list starts at index 0).

```
import math

l = [0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 3, 1]

result = l[2**math.floor(math.log(len(l), 2))-1]

print(result)
```

`math.log(x, 2)` gets you the number you need to raise 2 to to get `x`, `math.floor` gets you the integer part of that number, `2**x` raises 2 to the power of `x` and one is subtracted to get the correct element from the list.

If you really need to find the fastest solution using intermediate lists, or if all the lists have to be given as part of the actual answer, then I think you've already found a fairly optimal solution. Except that you're overwriting previous results with each iteration, so it seems you're not really after this.

Possibly, you could improve performance by changing the list into a more efficient type of array (built-in or numpy for example), manipulating that for the intermediate results and returning those. But if you need to return lists, that won't be much better as the conversion to and from that datatype will add cost that will likely eliminate the advantage of a faster selection.

Comment: Hey there!  Suppose my no of elements is:7  and list is:  l=[0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8]  So the expected answer is:2  but your code will give the output as:5

Comment: You're correct - there was a mistake in the initial answer, so you can either accept the amended answer, or accept @rahul verma's